# Deploying application to remote IIS server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I want to automate building and deploying process.

I managed to create a build definition on VSO and when I check in code build starts, tests run, and as an end product a folder is created which contains all my projects (asp.net web app and class libraries from solution) and bin folders from these projects.

But what I need is to get the same structure I get when I publish my web project from visual studio through publish feature (bin, Content, Scripts, Views, Web.config). And then copy all that to remote folder through ftp.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [release management capabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/release/overview) of Team Services (fka VSO) to your remote folder.

You can add a task to copy a file to a remote windows machine, do an Azure file copy, execute a powershell script and much more.

Answer (score 0):

I've setup all the deployment setting through the project > deploy and get it all working locally direct from VS. Then reference the build configuration through the msbuild switch on VSO. Using MSdeploy is by far the fastest, however it does support FTP.

[[Visual Studio Online continuous deployment to Azure Website with publish profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26548222/visual-studio-online-continuous-deployment-to-azure-website-with-publish-profile][1])

I've used it to deploy to a 3rd party hosting with on-site agent.